# Give a simple description of the intersection of the following set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

let:

$$\bigcap_{x \in [0,1]}(x-1,x+1)$$

to me this looks like just a collection of all the possible pairs of outputs which can be defined as a finite set the highest output is 2 and the lowest output is -1. So the set can be described as the interval $(-1,2]$ Is my interpretation off?

Comment: if you take $x = 1/2$. You get the interval $(-1/2, 3/2)$. But the point $2$ is not in this interval.

Comment: You seem to think of the union (though even then I don‘t see why you would include $2$).

Comment: By plugging 1 into x +1

Comment: "just a collection of all the possible pairs of outputs"  These aren't pairs; this are intervals.  "which can be defined as a finite set" There are uncountablely many $x \in [0,1]$ so how can this be a finite set. "the highest output is 2 and the lowest output is -1"  But highest an lowest input only occur once.  This is the *intersection* so only the values that *always* occur will be included.  If $x = 0.9$ then $(x-1,x+1) = (-0.1,1.9)$ and *neither* $2$ nor $-1$ occur so they are *NOT* in the intersection.  BTW why did you make $-1$ closed and $2$ open?

Comment: Because plugging in 1 gave me two and since 1 was closed i closed 2

Comment: I think iget it should be (-1,2) The intersection means its a collection of all the outputs

Comment: "The intersection means its a collection of all the outputs"  !!!NO!!!! The *UNION* is the collection of all outputs.  The *intersection* is just only the outputs that are in *EVERY* interval.  Take $1.5$.  $1.5 \in (.6 - 1, .6+1)$ but $1.5 \not \in (.4-1, .4 + 1)$.  So $1.5$ is *NOT* in the intersection.

Comment: If $w \ge 1$ then $w \not \in (0-1, 0+1)$ so $w$ will *not* be in the intersection.  Only elements that are in *every* interval will be in the intersection.  If $w \le 0$ then $w\not \in (1-1,1+1)$ so $w$ will not be in the intersection.

Comment: "By plugging 1 into x +1" and "Because plugging in 1 gave me two and since 1 was closed i closed 2".  But $2 \not \in (1-1, 1+1)$.  $2=1+1$ so $2 \not < 1+1$ so $2\not \in (1-1,1+1)$

Answer (score 1):

This is the *intersection* so you need the elements that will be in *all* the intervals $(x-1,x+1)$.

If $x = 0$ then $(x-1, x+1) = (-1, 1)$.  So nothing outside $(-1,1)$ can possibly be in the intersection.  (Because everything in the intersection must be in *all* the intervals, including this one. If $w \le -1$ then $w$ is not in the intersection and if $w \ge 1$ then $w$ is not in the intersection.

If $x = 1$ then $(x-1,x+1) = (0, 2)$ so nothing outside that interval can be in the intersection.  So if $w \le 0$ it is not in the intersection.

So the only elements that *can* be in the intersections are only the points in the interval $(0,1)$ but which of these can be in the intersection?

If $0 < w < 1$ and if $0\le x \le 1$ then $x+1 \ge 1 > w$ And $x-1 \le 0 < w$.  So $w\in (x-1,x+1)$.

So *every* $w\in (0,1)$ will be in *every* interval $[x-1,x+1]$ so every $w\in (0,1)$ *will* be in the intersection.  And no points that aren't in (0,1)$ will be.

So the intersection is $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

When $x=0$ we get $(-1,1)$.  When $x=1$ we get $(0,2)$.  These are the two extremes.  The intersection $\bigcap_{x\in[0,1]}(x-1,x+1)=(0,1)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Well, I'm just visualizing it.  To prove it,  note that $y\in(0,1)\implies y\in(x-1,x+1)\,,\forall x\in[0,1]$.  And conversely.

Comment: But we are only told that x isin the interval (0,1 ) what is the crucial idea that I am missing?

Comment: Let's see.  I guess I could be more convincing.   But, picture an open interval of width $2$ moving from being centered at $0$ to being centered at $1$.  What's the overlap?

Answer (score 0):

Intersection of (open) intervals is a common (overlapping) interval.

Note:
$$-1=\color{red}0-1\le x-1\le \color{red}1-1=\color{blue}{(0<1)}=\color{red}0+1\le x+1\le \color{red}1+1=2$$
So, the intersection is $\color{blue}{(0,1)}$.